Pull Down resitor in a npn 2n2222
I have a simial circuit to the one below with 2k base and the 2n2222 it's driven by a signal of about 100hz to 200hz with 0 to 100% duty cycle coming from a pic18f output pin 0 to 5v and IC load is about 20ma. Do I need this pull-down resistor for this application? I know that it will form a voltage divider, also the resistor will make the bjt turn off faster as well as deal with miller capacitances. will the micro pin help with this and thus not leave the base floating and not need for the pulldown?


Citi - Hi, Where did the original image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online, public & legal, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY

There's no real need for a pull-down resistor.
The PIC output is push-pull and slightly faster switching is not important in this application.
